# rails 5 validate count in associated scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a model called **Person**, and a model called **Contract**.  A **Person** *has_many* **Contracts**, and a **Contract** *belongs_to* a **Person**.

A **Contract** has a **start_date** and an **end_date**.  A Contract is considered **active** if the current date falls in between.

I have a *scope* on Contract called "**active**", which returns records accordingly.  A Person can have any number of inactive Contracts, but **should only have one** active Contract.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add validation that prevents any of these cases:

- Create a new active Contract with an associated Person that already has an active Contract.
- Change the associated Person on an existing active Contract to a Person that already has an active Contract.
- Change a Contract that isn't active to have a start_date or end_date that makes it active, when the associated Person already has an active Contract.
- Create a Person with multiple active Contracts associated.

This is what I'm currently doing, and it seems to work:

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  validates_uniqueness_of :person_id, conditions: -> { active }
  scope :active, -> { where("start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today) }
end
```

To me, it feels like a bit of a hack.  I'm not concerned with uniqueness, I'm concerned with size; it just happens that uniqueness works. What if I wanted to allow no more than 2 active contracts?

Also, the validation error that I get back when I try to add multiple active Contracts says, "Person is already taken", which is misleading. Sure, I can add a custom message, but it seems like another indication that I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: What about delegating the logic to Person? Make a scope like 'active_contract_count' on Person, and when a contract needs to be created, do it from Person from a method  like 'create_contracts(contracts)' which tests for active_contract_count  before attempting to create contracts, then also looks at each contract and tests them for .active? which returns if they are within the specified date range.

Comment: @bkimble Maybe, but what about validating updates to existing contracts?  It seems like it would get messy to try to perform all create/update contract operations through the person model.. It might work to prevent the unwanted conditions, but if I understand correctly, you're suggesting I don't use the built-in rails validation functionality? It seems to me like I'd be better off to use validates_with and a custom validator class at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the uniqueness missleading message, you can always customize messages on validations

```
validates :person_id, uniqueness: {scope: :active, message: 'Some custom message'}
```

For non standard validations you neeed a custom validator or a custom method for validation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods. You just need to add an error for an attribute (or :base if not related to an attribute) when some condition happens, condition could be checking dates, users, etc

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  validate :allow_only_two_active_contracts

private
  def allow_only_two_active_contracts
    person_contracts = person.contracts.active.where.not(id: self.id).count #count all active contracts of the person except this one, not sure if the where.not is necessary

    errors.add(:person_id, 'This person already has two active contracts') if person_contracts >= 2
  end
end
```

What ActiveRecord tries to validate your contract, it will call that method, and after all validations, if `errors` has shomething the record is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, yea seems like this may be the best way to go then.  For the record, I think your answer's logic is incomplete - we'd only want to add the error if the person_contracts >= 2 && self.active?  (if the contract being validated isn't active, then we shouldn't prevent saving it).

Comment: Oh yes, of course, you have more context and knowledge of the app to add the right conditions, mine was just an example on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the complete scenario correctly, you should not only check for uniqueness -> active. Else still when your active contract turns inactive - there could be two contracts, that were inactive that now get active.
And I agree that the validation should happen on the person (that should even solve your issue with changing relations).

So I think you want more something like:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :contracts, :not_overlapping
end

class NotOverlappingValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return if value.blank?
    mark_overlapping_error to_ranges(value)
  end

  def mark_overlapping_error(ranges)
    ranges[0..-2].each_with_index do |range, index|
      # check if successive contracts are overlapping in their active interval
      next unless range.overlaps?(ranges[index + 1])
      # add some custom error about the overlapping
      return record.errors.add attribute, :overlaps 
    end
  end

  def to_ranges(contracts)
    # mapping contracts to their activity-interval
    value.sort_by(&:start_date).map do |contract|
      (contract.start_date..contract.end_date)
    end
  end
end
```

This way you ensure from beginning, that a person never will get contracts, that are overlapping.

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer because it turns the logic around to focus on Person, but still keeps the contract validation logic in its own class.  This solution is more flexible, but I accepted arieljuod's answer because it solved my issue more directly.